# String cannot represent value GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm building a GraphQL API and in one of my endpoints I have this problem, it says that "message": "String cannot represent value: [\"Vitoria\", \"Serra\", \"Cariacica\", \"Vila Velha\"]".

I have tried to Change for type: GraphQLList.

```
const alfa_regions = [
    {ES_capital: ['Vitoria', 'Serra', 'Cariacica', 'Vila Velha']},
    {ES_Interior: ['Piuma', 'Sao Gabriel']},
    {MG_Capital: ['Contagem']},
    {MG_Interior: ['Juiz de fora', 'Governador Valadares', 'Teofilo Otoni', 'Monte Claros']},
]


const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLFloat,
    GraphQLList
} = graphql

const AlfaRegionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AlfaRegion',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLString},
        region_id: {type: GraphQLString},
        ES_capital: {type: GraphQLString},
    })
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        regions: {
            type: AlfaRegionType,
            args: {id: {type: GraphQLString}},
            resolve(parent, args){
                return _.find(alfa_regions, {})
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a field returns an array of strings, not just a single string, then you should use `GraphQLList` for the type as shown [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqllist):

```
type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
```

or using SDL

```
[String]
```

If the array won't contain any nulls, then it'd be even better to do

```
type: new GraphQLList(new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString))
```

or using SDL

```
[String!]
```

If the array won't contain any nulls *and* the field itself won't ever be null, then do:

```
type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)))
```

or using SDL

```
[String!]!
```